# Autofs mount problems

Tags: linux, mount, autofs

I need a suggestion how to configure autofs to mount a windows share automatically to CentOS.

I can successfully mount the share, but I can't seem to enter parameters into auto.master corectly.

Could someone look at my mount command (which executes correctly) and advise me what to put into auto.master?

```
mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=pass,rw,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 //server1/resources/50004 /var/www/html/resources/50004
```

The mount parameters must be the same. I want to use `auto.master` and `auto.50004`files.
Nothing else will be mounted, just the one directory above.
What should I put into `auto.master` and what into `auto.50004`?

Here is my auto.master:

```
/misc /etc/auto.misc
/net -hosts
+auto.master
/var/www/html/resources/50004 /etc/auto.50004
```

And my auto.50004:

```
/50004 -fstype=cifs,rw,user=user,pass=password,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 ://server1/resources/50004
```

Could someone please have a look, this is driving me mad

Comment: Take a look at "man 5 autofs" and afterwards show what exactly you have in your auto.master and auto.50004 files please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the exact same behavior with the same configuration -- and nothing in /var/log/messages (good or bad) when I restart autofs.

Answer (score 0):

Proper `/etc/auto.master` line:

```
/var/www/html/resources   /etc/auto.50004
```

Proper `/etc/auto.50004` content:

```
50004 -fstype=cifs,rw,user=user,pass=password,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 ://server1/resources/50004
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are far too many guides on AutoFS which overly complicate autofs setup. Assuming you're on an Ubuntu box, here are the easy instructions on setting it up.

Here's some very simple instructions:

- Install from apt-get: `sudo apt-get install autofs -y`
- Remove everything in `/etc/auto.master` and replace with: `/- /etc/auto.cifs --timeout=20 --ghost`
- Add one line like this to auto.cifs for each mount:`/mnt/LOCAL/MOUNT/PATH -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,credentials=/etc/auto.credentials ://SERVER/MOUNT`
- In `/etc/auto.credentials`, add the following content:

  `username=USERNAME
  password=PASSWORD`
- Finally, `sudo service autofs restart`.

That's it.